# Using Apache Thrift, what protocols are supported for which platforms?

Tags: thrift

I've been looking into using Apache Thrift, but find the documentation somewhat lacking. Right now I'm interested in seeing the target languages supported together with the protocols supported on each, is there such a matrix anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
[Thrift Language Support Matrix](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/LibraryFeatures)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this Matrix is useful, but slightly outdated (Delphi, Go, Graphviz not listed). The good news is, that there is only more options now, not less.